# Why can I not use IntelliJ IDEA (Community Edition) efficiently?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA on my Chromebook via Linux. I did so because I wanted to learn Kotlin (and use it productively). When I try to use it, however, I am greeted with slow response times. I've tried to optimize it via IntelliJ's settings, as well as through my own settings. Every time I try to run or load a KorGE Gradle project with just my browser opened, my CPU usage skyrockets to 100% and performs that way consistently until Intellij just can't handle it anymore and kills the instance of the program. I counted that I have about 96 thread dumps because of the UI freezing. Obviously, this is not how IntelliJ IDEA runs normally (or at least I assume based on watching other people use it). Also, if anyone has any tips as to how I can program productively in Visual Studio Code (my "go-to" IDE) that are other than installing the usual Kotlin extensions, I would love to hear them!

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What is the Chromebook's CPU & RAM?

Comment: @Martheen, my CPU is MediaTek mt8183. I am not sure about my RAM though. It seems (based on my research) that the MediaTek mt8183 is not very capable when it comes to processing games. Obviously, I am not using it for gaming, but this may be part of the problem.

Comment: That's a rather low-end CPU https://www.notebookcheck.net/Mediatek-MT8183-SoC-Benchmarks-and-Specs.445915.0.html, slower than basic Celeron N3350 commonly found on low end netbook, I found a review here https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/hp-chromebook-11a about a model where it's paired with slow eMMC and cramped 4 GB RAM, this is simply not a machine to run heavy IDEs. You might be better off applying for Oracle Cloud free tier offer, try to get their ARM VPS, then set up VS Code to be accessed remotely.

Comment: Nowadays, SSD is a must, make sure it's SSD instead of eMMC, 8 GB of RAM is also the minimum if you want IntelliJ with Gradle. Ideally a quad-core (AMD Ryzen tends to be cheaper than Intel Core). If you're on a tight budget an upgradable whitebox or refurbished laptop can be a good alternative.

Comment: To make sure the problem is related to the available resources please contact JetBrains support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the IDE logs. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)